# File transfer issue in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I am transferring files using c#. I have used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24017/File-Transfer-using-Socket-Application-in-C-NET-2) code. The problem is small files like .txt files are transferred correctly but not big files like images, documents, pdf, ppt. Sometimes code works fine but most of the times it transfers less amount of data.

**Server Code:**

```
Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 50000];
int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);
BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + "/" + fileName, FileMode.Append));
bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);
bWrite.Close();
clientSock.Close();
```

**Client Code:**

```
byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);
clientSock.Send(clientData);
clientSock.Close();
```

Complete code is given in the above link. I have also seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326649/c-sharp-mutlti-threading-file-transfer-using-tcp) but this is not helpful.

Comment: Are you using a  connection-oriented Socket or a connectionless Socket?

Comment: I am connecting using IP address and TCP to transfer data. I didn't understood what you said but i hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **CodeCaster's** answered that `Socket.Receive(), it doesn't always return all data that gets sent to it.` This is 100% correct and tested but the next step of sending the file size is not working, I found an easy and correct solution.

`Socket.Receive()` method takes the byte array in which received data will be copied and returns the number of bytes received. So we can easily loop it till bytes received are 0.

```
byte[] tempData = new byte[1024 * 5000];

BinaryWriter bWrite = null;
int bytes_received;
int fileNamelength = 0;
bool isFirstPacket = true;

do
{
    bytes_received = clientSock.Receive(tempData);
    if(isFirstPacket)
    {
        isFirstPacket = false;
        int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(tempData, 0);
        string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

        bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Append))
        bWrite.Write(tempData, 4 + fileNameLength, bytes_received - 4 - fileNamelength);
    }
    else
        bWrite.Write(tempData, 0, bytes_received);
}
while (bytes_received != 0);
```

Comment: yes, actually i kept on writing file inside do loop, i will try to include the file writing code in above post. i transferred files more than 600MB using this code.

Answer (score 4):

> Sometimes code works fine but most of the times it transfers less amount of data.

That's the nature of `Socket.Receive()`, it doesn't always return all data that gets sent to it.

You'll have to do a [`Receive(clientData, 4, 0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26f591ax) first to receive the bytes that indicate the `size` , then call `Receive(clientData)` in a loop until you've received `size` bytes. But beware that the `Receive(buffer[], length, offset)` overload just as easily as any other overload can return *less* than the expected amount of bytes. So you'll also have to call that in a loop:

Something like this:

```
// First receive the size
int sizeSize = 4; // Size of Int32 in bytes
int sizeOffset = 0;
var sizeBytes = new byte[sizeSize];
while (sizeOffset < sizeSize)
{
    sizeOffset += clientSocket.Receive(sizeBytes, sizeSize - sizeOffset, sizeOffset);
}

var size = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeBytes, 0);

// Then receive the data
byte[] fileData = new byte[size];
byte[] clientData = new byte[8192];
int totalBytes = 0;

while (totalBytes < size)
{
    // This may return anything between 0 and 8192, even if not all sent data has been received yet. It may be in a buffer somewhere, waiting to be picked up. Check for 0, since that's when the client disconnects.
    int bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(clientData);

    // You now have received a chunk of data of bytesReceived length. Append it into the fileData array.
    Buffer.BlockCopy(clientData, 0, fileData, totalBytes, bytesReceived);

    totalBytes += bytesReceived;
}
```

Comment: at server side I am already getting size of client data in **receivedBytesLen** and using it in **bWrite.Write()**

Comment: @AndroidLearner And if that worked like you expected, would you have this problem? You can set whatever you want on the server side, the client has no notion of this: it just receives an array of bytes. You can't dictate or predict how many you will receive in one `Receive()` call; you'll have to keep calling `Receive()` until you have read them all.

Comment: But **Receive(clientData, 4, 0)** always returns me 4

Comment: @AndroidLearner Yes, and then you can call `BitConverter.ToInt32()` on the bytes that that returned to determine how many bytes more you expect (i.e. `size`). Then you can either call `Receive(byte[])` in a loop until the sum of the result of that equals `size`, or you can call `Receive(byte[], size, 0)`. `Receive(byte[])` will return as soon as the sockets API decides it wants to present you some data, so one call to `Receive()` is rarely enough.

Comment: are you trying to say this thing? **client** `int sent = 0; while (sent < clientData.Length) sent += clientSock.Send(clientData);` **server** `int received = 0; while (received < TotalData) received += clientSock.Receive(clientData);`

Comment: the `size` variable is always 48, it's not getting the original size of the file.